# PHP MySQL : Load data infile add row index base on primary key

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

I am uploading CSV File using load data infile, how can I make row index to specific column.

```
$max_asset_id = 79;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
IGNORE INTO TABLE asset_mgt.asset_info
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@asset_id, @type_of_asset, @asset_description, @model, @serial_number, @asset_tagging_no, @quanity, @remarks)
SET asset_id = /*Add increment here $max_asset_id++ */,
type_of_asset = @type_of_asset,
asset_description = @asset_description,
model = @model,
serial_number = @serial_number,
asset_tagging_no = @asset_tagging_no,
quanity = @quanity,
remarks = @remarks
```

Comment: Maybe post some table data, but I feel you should probably be using an auto increment column here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my primary key has already auto-increment

Comment: Anyway I just make a Trigger `SET NEW.asset_id = (SELECT MAX(row_id)+1 from asset_mgt.asset_info);`